# difference between sparse.model.matrix and as.matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, xgboost

I am using xgboost in R to build a classification model on a training dataset `train`. `train` has following attributes.

1. it has all numeric features
2. no missing values.
3. no categorical/text/factor variables present.
4. `TARGET` is the target variable taking 1/0 values.

xgb.train requires data to be passed in a specific format, so I tried following 2 ways to get the format required by xgb.train.

1.

```
y <- train$TARGET
train <- sparse.model.matrix(TARGET ~ ., data = train) ##has 76000 rows and 307 columns
xgtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data=train, label=y)
```

2.

```
y <- train$TARGET
train$TARGET <- NULL
x = as.matrix(train)
x = matrix(as.numeric(x),nrow(x),ncol(x)) ##has 76000 rows and 307 columns
xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(x, label = y)
```

**Now, when I score the test set using the model built by these 2 `xgtrain` creating methods, I get different scores/AUC. I have verified that it is not the problem with randomization since I have been able to reproduce the scores if I run 1st method or 2nd method twice/thrice. Something is happening differently in the 2 methods which I have not been able to figure out. Can somebody please help me identify that difference?**

Question in another words.
***What does `sparse.model.matrix` do differently from `as.matrix` when the data provided to them has only numeric features with no missing values and no categorical variables?***

Answer (score 1):

using a formula (in sparse.model.matrix) adds an intercept to your data (e.g. a column with all 1s). So the two matrices you have are different, and hence the different results. To avoid that use:

```
train = sparse.model.matrix(TARGET~.-1,data = train)
```

Also, it is probably not a good idea to override your dataset with the data model matrix (naming both "train")

Comment: but when I check columns using ncol(train) before and after, it is coming out to be same. Why?

Comment: @user3664020 In the first example the matrix still has the Target column, in the second example you delete this column and adds the intercept to the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

```
> data <- 
+     data.table(
+         a=c(1,2,NA)
+         ,b=c(3,NA,4)
+     ) %>%
+     mutate_all(as.factor)
> data %>% 
+     sparse.model.matrix(a ~.-1,data=.)
1 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  b3 b4
1  1  .
> data %>% 
+     as.matrix()
     a   b  
[1,] "1" "3"
[2,] "2" NA 
[3,] NA  "4"
```

You will find after using `sparse.model.matrix` method, the rows with missing value are forced to be dropped.